# Technique for building a Multiplayer Server

Tags: node.js, multiplayer

I'm looking to write my own multiplayer game server (most likely in nodejs) and I was wondering what protocol I should be using to transfer data? Are Datagrams the norm to send information (i realize they don't confirm delivery like HTTP, that can written on top of the protocol)? Any suggestions of performant proven systems would be a real help.

I guess I'm looking for successful techniques in handling the data transfer quickly and effectively (maintaining state on the server and scaling are a separate issue that I have a solid understanding of).

I'm looking to initially support desktop/mobile games (MacOS, iOS, and Android).

Comment: I've read that UDP is preferred for streaming live data. TCP will retry to send data which isn't what you want if the data is live. Imagine that a client is having issues getting packets, so they constantly have to be resent, that client will be getting old packets and get a lag effect. Or so that's how I understood it

Comment: @Spidy you can't use UDP with `node.js`

Comment: The system I'm thinking about will probably support both types of communication: Confirmed and unconfirmed delivery. Since they are both useful in different situations. So would I need to have a UDP and TCP connection open if a game uses both (or just implement confirmed delivery in UDP)?

Comment: @Raynos - as of a couple weeks ago node.js supports UDP ;) http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/dgram.html

Comment: @Shakakai that's not UDP to the browser.

Comment: I never stated this was for a browser. Probably just Desktop/Mobile games at first.

Comment: UDP is a good choice for online real-time communication. It can confirm the delivery of your data. You may check this article as an reference for designing multiplayer games[link](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Latency_Compensating_Methods_in_Client/Server_In-game_Protocol_Design_and_Optimization)

Comment: @sky100 oh noes...the article has a heading called "Umm, This is a Lot of Work" :P Good link though

Comment: For general multiplayer client support node.js is probably a poor choice, unless you want to lead the development of a new project yourself! If you have no objection to Python, you may get some interesting suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all your protocol needs take a look at [socketIO](http://socket.io/).

Basically your best solution is to rely on websockets which are TCP sockets. socketIO is just a nice cross-browser compliant abstraction.

Either you use standard long pulling techniques or html5 websockets. There is no access to UDP for browser <-> server.

Comment: socketIO looks pretty slick - if I get around to support HTML5 games, I'll definitely dig into it.

Comment: @Shakakai I'm looking at writing a multiplayer game server myself. Just going to stick to TCP and chrome. Also go read the [gaffer](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/) articles

Answer (score 1):

There is a technology that is called [RTMFP](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) that Adobe introduced in the latest version of Flash (Flash 10). It allows you to do P2P connection and transfer data directly from a client to an other client without passing by the server. On top of that, it's using UDP to transfer data. I believe that this was originally designed to do video and audio streaming, but you can use it to pass data around.

However the main downside on this technology is the mobile since most of them don't support Flash. In this case you can use Socket.IO and use the server as a router of information as a fallback.

If you want to build your application in Javascript, you can still use it by bridging the functionnality to Javascript. If you want to take a look at a simple version of a bridge, you can take a look at [this github project](https://github.com/HoLyVieR/RTMFP-JS-Bridge) (I am the author).

Comment: If RTMP was supported by multiple languages other than Flash, it'd be interested. I'm looking for something a little more open so I can implement it on iOS (Objective-C), Android (Java), and Unity3D (Mono).

Answer (score 0):

As a C++ developer of Massive Multiplayer games for 10 years, I can tell you that most of your more advanced games, such as ones in which I was involved (Legends Of Kesmai, Magic: The Gathering Online, Airwarrior II, AVP, NTN Triva) to name a few, TCP is used for most communication simply because you need an ACK / NACK to be sure the data was received from the client.  That is not to say UDP doesn't have it's place.  In Legends we wrote the the protocol code to use UDP for out of bandwidth delivery of data which wasn't imperative that it be received in proper packet order and complete.  Use UDP when you want to do things like update graphic files in the background while the user is playing, etc.  This type of delivery is often used for such purposes and allows your TCP packets to arrive as required by your server.